# Selenium Grid low on threads

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We are using AWS servers (EC2) as nodes for a Selenium Grid, and the hub is within our local deployment server environment.

We are starting the nodes with the following command:

```
%~dp0jdk1.8.0\bin\java -jar %~dp0selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role node -hub http://seleniumgrid.ourhost.com:80/grid/register -port 80 -host 1.1.1.1 -maxSession 5
```

This starts up ok, but we seems to have intermittent running of the hubs. It registers the node to the hub, but almost instantly after that:

```
07:32:35.134 WARN - OUT OF THREADS: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:80
07:32:35.136 WARN - OUT OF THREADS: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:80
07:32:36.201 INFO - LOW ON THREADS ((512-512+1)<2) on SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:80
```

While the tests eventually start running, we receive lots of errors in the results:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Session [6c4d2b4d-0b1f-464b-9ddc-bee3c1f95fba] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED
```

I'm at a loss, and not sure what we can do to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug in version 2.42.* See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7396 for more details.

Comment: please add relevant part of that link in your answer